# Using a while () loop to subtract numbers from the sum

Tags: c++

I am trying to subtract the initial value that I gave my code from the sum and then have that sum be subtracted by the initial value - 1. For example, my number is 4 so 0+1+2+3+4= 10 and then have 4 subtract from 10 to get 6, then 6 subtracted by 3 to get 3, and so on. I'm extremely new to c++ and I just need a nudge in the right direction.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int sum = 0;

void main() {

cout << "Please give me a number" << endl;
cin >> a;

do {
    if (a <= 0) {
    cout << "Incorrect number. The input must be positive" << endl;
        cin >> a;
    }
} while (a <= b);

for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
    cout << i;
    cout << "+";
    sum += i;
}

cout << endl;
cout << "All numbers from 0 to " << a << " is " << sum << endl;
cout << "Starting with the sum of " << sum << endl;

while (a > 0) {
    c = sum - a;
    cout << "After subtracting " << a << ", I got the number " << c << endl;
    a--;
}
```

Comment: `void main()` - that's *not* valid C++. `main` *always* returns `int`, *never* `void`.

Comment: wouldnt for (int i = a; i >= 0; i--) {} aka loop backwards solve it for you?

Comment: Perhaps you just need to start out with `c = sum`, followed by `c -= a` in the loop?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that first loop would be better written as `while (a <= 0) { std::cout << "input must be positive\n"; std::cin >> a; }`. That way there's only one comparison, and things are clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int sum = 0;

int main() {

cout << "Please give me a number" << endl;
cin >> a;

do {
    if (a <= 0) {
    cout << "Incorrect number. The input must be positive" << endl;
        cin >> a;
    }
} while (a <= b);

for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
    cout << i;
    cout << "+";
    sum += i;
}

cout << endl;
cout << "All numbers from 0 to " << a << " is " << sum << endl;
cout << "Starting with the sum of " << sum << endl;

c = sum;  /*Initialize c */
while (a > 0) {

    c = c - a;
    cout << "After subtracting " << a << ", I got the number " << c << endl;
    a--;
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: I think you meant to edit this into your question? Unless the small changes are things you think fixed it, in which case you need to describe the fixes; a code dump that's 99% identical is not useful to most people. If you meant to edit your question, do so, then delete this answer.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much

Comment: Next time, don't post only code as an answer.  Add explanation as to how your code differs from the OP and how your code resolves the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int a;
    int sum = 0;

    int main() {
    cin>>a;

    while(a<=0){
    cin>>a;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= a; i++){ cout<<i; cout<<"+"; sum+=i;}

    while(a > 0){
      sum-=(a--);
    }
   }
```